# Where Can I Download Chrome OS?

Tags: linux, disk-image, chrome-os, chrome-book, reinstall

A few months ago, I bought a Chromebook CR-48 Mario on eBay and I "modded" it and flashed a new BIOS and installed a different Linux version. Now I want to re-install Chrome OS. Where can I download the .img or .iso for Chrome OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get most releases at http://getchrome.eu/download.php

For official documentation from Google on recovering your device go to: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1080595?hl=en

Comment: I saw this with the ".eu", and it's not https, so I wasn't sure.

Comment: It even supports HTTPS: https://getchrome.eu/download.php

Comment: This looks like spam, it brought me to a sketchy site filled with ads and a CAPTCHA that doesn't seem to work and it makes me wait 1 minute before starting...

Comment: There's multiple links for the USB image...

Comment: I just tried the download and it looks OK.  Because of your worries, I looked further and found a recovery document from Google which I added to my answer.

Comment: *`Chromium 24.0.1290 web browser New!`* I doubt this is the right one the current release for Chrome/Chromium is 57 and Chrome OS does not include Gimp, LibreOffice, Cinnamon, ***Wine*** (!?)…

Answer (score 0):

The [Recover your Chromebook](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1080595?hl=en) link is the proper one for restoring your Chromebook with default firmware, but you said you flashed another (BIOS) firmware so steps to recover from that depend on what that was. A popular choice is [MrChromebox](https://mrchromebox.tech/) firmware utility script which includes restoring the stock firmware, but I have never used this functions because my Chromebooks cannot be modded very much.

Notice that [Mario/Cr-48](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices) is end of life since Chrome OS M56 (latest release currently is M57, M58 is just around the corner), but I guess you know that, some people around here though may not.

There are also ChromiumOS builds from [ArnoldTheBat](https://arnoldthebat.co.uk/wordpress/) and [Hexxeh](http://blog.hexxeh.net/projects) (seems like he has moved on to other projects). I don't know how these will run on Chrome OS devices and particularly on EoL'ed devices, you have to try that out for yourself.

I'm not sure if this helps, but there is also the following page about [Mario](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Support/Pineview) in the hardware support section of GalliumOS, a popular Xubuntu-based Linux which I use on my Chromebooks.